# How to load an image into imageView using a Uri and Bitmap Factory

Tags: android, imageview

I am passing a Uri to a new activity and trying to use it to create an imageView in the new activity. I use an InputStream and a BitmapFactory to achieve this. My picture keeps showing as black, though, and I am not sure why.

First_Page:

```
public void galleryClicked(View view){

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);

    File pictureDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    String pictureDirectoryPath = pictureDirectory.getPath();

    Uri data = Uri.parse(pictureDirectoryPath);

    intent.setDataAndType(data, "image/*");

    startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK ){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Tattoo_Page.class);
        intent.putExtra("picture", data.getData());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Tattoo_Page:

```
public class Tattoo_Page extends Activity {

private ImageView picture;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.tattoo_page);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    picture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picture);

    Uri imageUri = (Uri) extras.get("picture");


    try {

        InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);

        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

        picture.setImageBitmap(image);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to open image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

}

XML:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/picture"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.any" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <activity android:name=".First_Page">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Tattoo_Page"> </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: Do you have set permissions for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform exact task using the code below:

```
public void galleryClicked(View v){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), 0);
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
        String[] fileColumns = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImageUri, fileColumns, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int cIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(fileColumns[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(cIndex);
        cursor.close();
        if (picturePath != null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Tattoo_Page.class);
            intent.putExtra("picture", picturePath);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Tatoo_Page Activity

```
public class Tattoo_Page extends Activity {

public static int IMAGE_MAX_WIDTH=1024;
public static int IMAGE_MAX_HEIGHT=768;
private ImageView picture;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.tattoo_page);

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
picture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picture);

String imagePath =  extras.getStringExtra("picture");


new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                final Bitmap bitmap = decodeFile(new File(picturePath));
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    Tatoo_Page.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            picture.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        }
                    });
                }else{
                        Toast.makeText(Tatoo_page.this,"Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(ProfileFragment.this.getActivity(),"Problem loading file",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }).start();

}
//This function will decode the file stream from path with appropriate size you need. 
//Specify the max size in the class 
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) throws Exception{
    Bitmap b = null;

    //Decode image size
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, null, o);
    fis.close();

    int scale = 1;
    int IMAGE_MAX_SIZE=Math.max(IMAGE_MAX_HEIGHT,IMAGE_MAX_WIDTH);
    if (o.outHeight > IMAGE_MAX_HEIGHT || o.outWidth > IMAGE_MAX_WIDTH) {
        scale = (int)Math.pow(2, (int) Math.ceil(Math.log(IMAGE_MAX_SIZE /
                (double) Math.max(o.outHeight, o.outWidth)) / Math.log(0.5)));
    }

    //Decode with inSampleSize
    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o2.inSampleSize = scale;
    fis = new FileInputStream(f);
    b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, null, o2);
    fis.close();

    return b;
}
```

Comment: Wow! That was a quick turnaround time to write all that code. I'll test it now. Thanks.

Comment: Make sure you write up code for runtime permissions if testing on Marshmallow and above devices.

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing an image within the main thread. It's highly inappropriate as it may slow down your app and probably drop framerate until memory loads finishes.

There's an awesome lib that abstract the entire process in a sub-thread and applying it into the layout.

Enter [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/). You include it into your project by adding `compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'` to your project dependencies and then you just write this simple line to download images from web:

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

As you are dealing with disk images you may want to use this loader instead:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(new File(...)).into(imageView);
```

And that's it. You are done.

As a bonus, many common pitfalls of image loading on Android are handled automatically by Picasso::

- Handling `ImageView` recycling and download cancelation in an adapter.
- Complex image transformations with minimal memory use.
- Automatic memory and disk caching.

Also, it is incredibly faster and lightweight. Much faster than almost any implementation out there (if not THE faster), the ENTIRE jar file has only 118 kb.

**TL;DR:**

Use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/). All the cool kids are doing it.

Comment: Interesting. I'm not loading from a URL, though.  Will this still work for native images?